# Strictly formal definition of a bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a strictly formal definition of a bipartite graph. I just found a bunch of explanations but never a strictly formal definition of the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A graph $G=(V,E)$ is bipartite if there exist $V_1,V_2\subseteq V$ such that $V=V_1\cup V_2$, $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$ and each edge $\in E$ has one endpoint in $V_1$ and one in $V_2$.

Alternatively: If there exists $V_1\subseteq V$ such that each edge $\in E$ has exactly one endpoint in $V_1$.

Comment: Alternatively: if $\chi(G)=2$. (Of course, then you might very well ask for a formal definition of the chromatic number $\chi(G)$...)